# Mockito NOT throwing exception with REST controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, mockito

I am facing an issue with my REST Controller unit tests (code given below).

The problem is "testInsertFailure" is not throwing the BusinessException, if I am passing the "customer" object i.e., the test case fails (java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<400> but was:<201>). This is because it is NOT reaching the ControllerAdvice as there is NO exception thrown.

**However, if I replace the "customer" object with Mockito.any(Customer.class), then the testcase is able throw BusinessException and it gets PASSED.**

But, I don't need to do (Mockito.any(Customer.class)) this for the "testInsertSuccess" test case, it works straight away with "customer" object itself.

**My query is why do I need to do "Mockito.any(Customer.class)" only for throwing an Exception ?** Could you please help me to understand on how this works.

**CustomerController Class:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("customers")
public class CustomerController {
    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;

    @RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.POST })
    public ResponseEntity<String> create(@RequestBody Customer customer) {
        customerService.insert(customer);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body("customer created successfully");
    }
}
```

**CustomerControllerTest Class:**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CustomerControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    private Customer customer;
    private String customerJSON;

    @Mock
    private CustomerService customerService;

    @InjectMocks
    private CustomerController customerController = new CustomerController();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {  
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(customerController)
                .setMessageConverters(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter())
                .setControllerAdvice(new CustomerControllerAdvice ()).build();
        customer = new Customer();
        customer.setId(1);
        customer.setName("Sara");
        customerJSON = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(customer);
    }

    @Test
    public void testInsertSuccess() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(customerService.insertOrUpdate(customer)).thenReturn(customer);
        mockMvc.perform(post("/customers").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(customerJSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().isCreated());
    }

    @Test
    public void testInsertFailure() throws Exception {

        Mockito.when(customerService.insert(customer))
                .thenThrow(new BusinessException("CustomerName", "CustomerName already in use"));

        //If I replace the above line with Mockito.any, the testcase passes
        //Mockito.when(customerService.insert(Mockito.any(Customer.class))
        //      .thenThrow(new BusinessException("CustomerName", "CustomerName already in use"));


        mockMvc.perform(post("/customers").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(customerJSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
    }
}
```

**CustomerControllerAdvice Class for handling Exceptions:-**

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomerControllerAdvice {
    @ExceptionHandler(BusinessException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleBusinessException(BusinessException businessExe) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(businessExe.getErrorMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Seeing the stacktrace would help us, I think

Comment: The entire problem is that there is no Exception thrown by the service layer (Customer service), so no exception stack trace available to share.

Comment: But you definitely should see any output after running the test, shouldn't you?

Comment: java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<400> but was:<201>
 at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:60)
 at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:89)
 at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers$10.match(StatusResultMatchers.java:655)
 at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:171)
 at biz.cogitare.trainserv.controllers.ProjectControllerTest.testInsertFailureWithProjectNameAlreadyExists(ProjectControllerTest.java:76)

Comment: The above stack trace found during passing the "customer" object.

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand why using real object in test doesn't throw any exception, but testing my software I actually use Mockito#any. It lets the test pass even if the setup changes. So say, the test with your actual customer will throw a BusinessException and will pass. Changing the customer to a new one could cause the test fail and not throwing the Ex. Using Mockito#any you no more need to care about instances being passed to the method and therefore the test will pass.

Comment: This probably means that `customer` inside the `create()` method is not equal to the one that was deserialized from the JSON string. Debug the test case to find out how they differ.